# how do i set up angular js services

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, rest, frameworks, angularjs

I'm building an app to manage an employee rewards program and I figured I would try and learn some of these new js frameworks I keep hearing about so I decided to check out Angular. Now I'm hoping someone who has actually used this framework can help build a quick example for me.

What I'm stuck on now is how to make complex angular models and a service to keep it in sync with the REST backend.

I'm not sure how to word this properly but.. I would like to have an employee (model?) that has an account (another model?) and that account would have many transactions (models?) at least that's how I have my database set up right now. The accounts and transaction data are like a bank account of a bonus bucks that employees can earn. The employees, accounts, and transactions are located at URIs like http://api.mydomain.com/employees /accounts /transactions

I already know how the data-binding and interaction works and I've been able to use the $http service to successfully GET JSON data from my server but it's watching the model for changes, validating and keeping in sync with the backend server that's got me stumped.

So I'd really appreciate any help to get the ball rolling :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to build a "pure" RESTful app with angular.js that for each end-point on the backend you create an associated model on the front-end and you create, read,update and delete the resource at the end point you should use [`$resource`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) plugin insted of `$http`.

[Here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2433-Using-RESTful-Controllers-In-An-AngularJS-Resource.htm) is an article to help you get started.